# How can i extract keyword from pdf file asp.net c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, text-extraction

I have cv in `pdf` format and i want to extract keyword NLP (Natural language processing).Here is attached images.

But i don't know how to do it ,I'm beginner please help me Thanks 
[img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L9Nrj.png) [img2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dQpdC.png)

Comment: http://asp.syncfusion.com/demos/reporting/pdf/import%20and%20export/TextExtraction/CS/Default.aspx

Comment: Thanks for response.Let me check please

Comment: Thanks for reply but how can i do this pragmatically using asp.net c#

Comment: you need to write the parser of your own then

Comment: Can you provide me sample code/example of parser please

Answer (score 0):

There is open source library called [iTextSharp](https://sourceforge.net/projects/itextsharp/).

You can just upload CV and place it on server at specific path then you can read it's contents in string and see whether your text exist there as below.

```
public bool KeywordExists(string keyWord)
{
    using (PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(pdfPath))
    {
        StringBuilder strText = new StringBuilder();    
        for (int i = 1; i <= reader.NumberOfPages; i++)
        {
            strText.Append(PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage(reader, i));
            if(strText.Contains(keyWord)) return true;
        }
        return false;
     }
}
```

Comment: If the goal is simply checking the existence of keyWord, why not running Contains immediately in every page? That way if the keyWord exist on early pages, the method can return immediately without having to extract from later pages.

Comment: @Martheen thanks for the comment, have made changes.

Comment: let me check please